# Nepenthes ice watering

Tags: carnivorous-plants, nepenthes

I have read about watering orchids with ice which slowly releases water and doesn't over water and I figured watering my highland nepenthes with frozen distilled water would be a good idea and they seem to love the small amount of cooling the ice creates making nighttime temps perfect along with the slow release if water. They are flourishing and my humidity is staying higher for some reason in the terrarium too. I'm just wondering if anyone else has tried this and their results but after trying it on some of my ventricosa hybrids I recommend it to others.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't think it makes too much of a difference. I seriously doubt that the slow release has anything to do with it. It might save some water since sphagnum moss can take a while to absorb water. The temperature change might be good for them though.